# jQuery Tab Containers + Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

here is my javascript code:

```
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.tab_menu li:first").addClass("selected").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

//On Click Event
$("ul.tab_menu li a").click(function() {
    $("ul.tab_menu li a").removeClass("selected"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("selected"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
    return false;
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/MonicaPonciano/rs75z/

I am using this in a html page (which includes a script tag with jquery) that is opened in an iframe, but the links do not work and looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody know what might be causing this?
Thx

Comment: Your jsFiddle example looks fine here.

Comment: Do you have any errors on the Console? Maybe another script is breaking this one.

Comment: agree with @MelanciaUK

Comment: yes.. that is the problem, when i use it inside a html page that is called inside an iframe, it doesn't work.

Comment: Inspect this page and check for errors. Make sure the jQuery library is being loaded.

Comment: Damn, it was a silly mistake! I forgot to put my code inside $ (function () {}); sorry guys ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put the code inside JS `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`